# ng-repeat add item only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Using AngularJS is there a way to add an item only once. For this snippet of code below say I enter F and add it to the list of items. Is there a way to restrict me or any user from adding F again?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">{{item}}</li>
        </ul>
        <input ng-model="newItem" type="text"></input>
        <button ng-click="add(newItem)">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
    $scope.add = function(item) {
        $scope.items.push(item);
    };

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ES5**

You have to check it manually in your method.

```
$scope.add = function (item) {
    if ($scope.items.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        $scope.items.push(item);
    }
};
```

---

**ES6**

You can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

> The Set object lets you store **unique** values of any type

```
$scope.items = new Set(["A", "B", "C", "D"]);

$scope.add = function (item) {
    $scope.items.add(item);
};
```

Comment: Thanks this helps alot!

Comment: Hi GG. quick question is there a way to check manually with the ES5 method you displayed using item id instead of item? Say for example $scope.items = [{"name": 'A', id: 0}, {"name": "B", id: 1}, {"name": "C", id: 2}, {"name": "D", id: 3}];

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the `push()` function to add the new item in the array, you can search if you find an identical item inside the array.

In that case I would edit the code like this:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

    $scope.add = function(item) {
        var found = false;

        for(var i = 0; i< $scope.items.length; i++){
          if(item == scope.items[i])
            found = true;
            return; //end the for loop
        }

        //new item not found in the array
        if(!found) $scope.items.push(item);
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's `Array.prototype.some` to check if the element is already and add based on that:

```
$scope.add = function(item) {

    if (!$scope.items.some(isAlreadyPresent)) {
      $scope.items.push(item);
    } else {
      console.log('item already present');
    }

    function isAlreadyPresent(ele) {
      return ele === item;
    }
};
```

Refer MDN for more details about `some`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some